# How can we hide a property in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a model say under

```
public class Device
{        
        public int DeviceId { get; set; }
        public string DeviceTokenIds { get; set; }
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
        public string FilePwd { get; set; }        
}
```

Now I have a ASP.net Web API where there is a POST method as under

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddDeviceRegistrations")]
public void InsertDeviceRegistrations(Device device)
```

If I expose the WebAPI, obviously all the fields will be available e.g.

```
{
  "DeviceId": 1,
  "DeviceTokenIds": "sample string 2",
  "Data": "QEBA",
  "FilePwd": "sample string 3"
}
```

What I want is that, whenever I expose my WebAPI, the DeviceID should not get expose. I mean I am looking for

```
{

      "DeviceTokenIds": "sample string 2",
      "Data": "QEBA",
      "FilePwd": "sample string 3"
}
```

Is it possible? If so how?

I can solve the problem by changing the function signature as

```
public void InsertDeviceRegistrations(string deviceTokenIds, byte[] data, string FilePwd).
```

But I wanted to know if it can be possible or not ?
If so , how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698844/how-to-use-shouldserializemembername-method-for-a-property-of-type-object

Comment: You can use "internal" access specifier for "DeviceId"
    internal int DeviceId {get; set; }

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I just figured out

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
 public int DeviceId { get; set; }
```

The namespace is `System.Runtime.Serialization`

More information [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Learnt something new today.

Thanks All.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: This works, but if you are using the same data model for GET operations, those fields will be missing.

Answer (score 5):

There's good practice to use View Models for all GET/POST requests.
In you case you should create class for receiving data in POST:

```
public class InsertDeviceViewModel
{        
    public string DeviceTokenIds { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public string FilePwd { get; set; }        
}
```

and then map data from view model to you business model `Device`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `Newtonsoft.Json`

you can hide the properties like this:

```
public class Product
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string internalID { get; set; };
    public string sku { get; set; };
    public string productName { get; set; };
}
```

and your serialized response will not include the internalID property.

Answer (score 2):

The use of the Attribute [NonSerialized] on top of the Property stops its from being Serialized in the outputting JSON/XML .

```
public class Device
{        
        [NonSerialized]
        public int DeviceId { get; set; }

        public string DeviceTokenIds { get; set; }
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
        public string FilePwd { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Hi, i just figured out [IgnoreDataMember]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the data member of Resonse class with null parameter. Go to your project WebApiConfig file residing in App_start folder, add the following code:

```
var jsonConfig = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
jsonConfig.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```