# How to show custom request examples in the .net api documentation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, documentation

```
    /// <summary>
    /// updates information of a job
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="job"></param>
    /// <returns>Ok or Error</returns>
    /// <example>
    /// {
    ///     "info_id": 1,
    ///     "some_other_id": 2
    /// }
    /// </example>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/job/update")]
    public IHttpActionResult update(Models.Job job) {
    }

    //the model
    public class Job {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Range(1, Int64.MaxValue)]
        public Int64 info_id { get; set; }
        public Int64? some_other_id{ get; set; }
        public DateTime last_log_time { get; set; }
    }
```

Imagine the setup above. I would like to show the example JSON written inside the doc block of `update` in the documentation. However, there is shown the serialized JSON of an object typed `Job` with default values instead.

[image]

I don't want developers to think they could or should provide `last_log_time` to function `update`. This property shall be shown in a response message, but not sent to the api.
How can I customize the examples for the requests formats per function? Ideally I would state it inside the doc block as shown (the API should only take requests in JSON-format), or maybe per annotations on the properties of the `Job`-class.

[How can we hide a property in WebAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610399/how-can-we-hide-a-property-in-webapi) the answer provodided here does not help because, as stated above, `last_log_time` shall be given in the response. If I annotate it with `[IgnoreDataMember]` it will be ignored globally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we hide a property in WebAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610399/how-can-we-hide-a-property-in-webapi)

Comment: @gpro explained why it isn't

Answer (score 0):

You can add `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` to your last_log_time property, but it only hides last_log_time in body parameters.

If you want to hide in sample format, you need customize source code of method `WriteSampleObjectUsingFormatter` at file `Areas\HelpPage\SampleGeneration\HelpPageSampleGenerator.cs`