# C# REST API - Decorate Entities returned by GET with an ID field

Tags: c#, rest, design-patterns, architecture

#### Background

When a consumer interacts with my REST API using POST/PATCH/PUT verbs I do not want to expose an entity that includes an ID field. The reason is that this field should not be modified by the consumer of the API at all.

But, when the consumer retrievs an entity using GET, I want the ID of the entity to be exposed.

**Example:**

This POST takes a entity of type Product as an argument. This Product does not have an ID field since this will be autogenerated by the API. In the response object, the product including its autogenerated ID is returned.

[image]

**Question:**
How do I achieve this in a nice maintainable way?

#### Possible Solutions

I've identified two ways of doings this that doesn't include magic and plays well with the autogenerated swagger documentation .

**First solution:**
Create a base class without an identifier and then a subclass that inherits from this and adds an ID field.

*Base class:*

```
public class Product
{       
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public string Category { get; set; }     
    public double Price { get; set; }       
    public DateTimeOffset DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

*Subclass:*

```
public class IdentifiedProduct : Product
{             
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

*Result in swagger:*
[image]

**Drawback:**
In effect, I will double the number of entities in every layer of my API.

---

**Second solution:** Add a generic decorator class

*Generic decorator:*

```
public class IdentifiedEntity<EntityType> where EntityType : class
{      
    public Guid Id { get; set; }       
    public EntityType Entity { get; set; }
}
```

*Result in swagger:*

[image]

**Drawback:**
Ugly json object

---

Any better solutions?

Comment: I understand that you want some generic solution (for example, annotation), but could you use mapping to DTO objects?

Comment: @Matt That's correct, or atleast a generic pattern that I could follow. 
Regarding the mapping you've mentioned. I'm not quite sure I fully understand you. I would love to see an example.

Comment: I meant like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/gMrhUH . This is made by hand, but you could use something like Automapper to speed up the process.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the example! That's also a solution but it has the same issue as my first solution. I would have to have one Entity and one EntityDTO for every abstraction I create in every layer of my API. Also, if I needed to change the fields in Entity I would have to change them in EntityDTO aswell :(

Comment: Take a look at this, try it out and report back with results https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610399/how-can-we-hide-a-property-in-webapi . I'am also interested in this question and solution to it :)

Comment: @Matt Glad you're interested. This has been a nuisance of mine for some time now. I've seen similar solutions before. Let's say I have one entity called Product as listed above. I could mark the Id field with the attribute  [IgnoreDataMember] but then both the response object and the request object would not have the Id field. I need the ID field to be present in the response object :/
There's a thread about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851207/prevent-property-from-being-serialized-in-web-api

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but as I can see that you are using Swagger, maybe there is some way to hide the property from Swagger configuration. As far as the general visibility of the property, I don't think there is an elegant solution for that. In the end, you can always ignore or set to null (in controller) whatever value customer sends in ID field ;)