# Hide properties from web api response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to hide `Modifiedby`, `Modifieddate` and `Createddate` properties from web api response.

I tried using `[JsonOgnore]`, `[IgnoreDataMember]` but non worked.

```
[ModelMetadataType(typeof(UserModel))]
partial class TUsers
{
}

public class UserModel
{
    public int Userid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Middlename { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public int? Modifiedby { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modifieddate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Createddate { get; set; }
}


    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = _service.GetUser(id);
            return Ok(new { status = Constants.Success, message = "", User = user });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(new { status = Constants.Failed, message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Actual Result

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "",
    "user": {
        "userid": 0,
        "firstname": null,
        "middlename": null,
        "lastname": null,
        "modifiedby": null,
        "modifieddate": null,
        "createddate": null
    }
}
```

Expected Result

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "",
    "user": {
        "userid": 0,
        "firstname": null,
        "middlename": null,
        "lastname": null
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `[JsonIgnore]` not `[JsonOgnore]` (is it a typo?), and should works

Comment: `[JsonIgnore]` will work if you are returning that class in your Web Api Response. It might be useful to see how you are also returning the data?

Comment: create separate Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) containing only properties you want to expose to your client and map your models to DTOs when sending back response.

Comment: If you class UserModel is something that reflects DB entity, I usually use another class (e.g. UserViewModel) to return from WebApi, and then I populate just required properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we hide a property in WebAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610399/how-can-we-hide-a-property-in-webapi)

Answer (score 10):

Simply, You can use the below attribute.

```
[JsonIgnore]
public int? Modifiedby { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've mentioned using `[JsonOgnore]` it should be `[JsonIgnore]` on the properties you want to exclude, this should work.

However instead of passing `User` object you can create `UserModel` that has exactly the properties you need and then pass `UserModel` object to the Response, but here you need to map the properties from `User` to `UserModel` but'll be more readable than excluding properties from being serialized.