# Hide parameter in API body

Tags: c#, api, swagger

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }    
}
```

dto class

```
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
       
    public string infoAdress{get; set;}
        
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }     
}
```

get method

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EmployeeDto>>> GetEmployees()
{
    return await _context.Employees
        .ProjectTo<EmployeeDto>(_imapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();
}
```

body api is:

```
{
    "employeeId": 0,
    "lastName": "string",
    "firstName": "string",
    "adressInfo": "string",
    "address": "string",
    "city": "string",
    "region": "string",
    "postalCode": "string",
    "country": "string"
  }
```

I want the method to return me only this data:

```
{
    "employeeId": 0,
    "lastName": "string",
    "firstName": "string",
    "adressInfo": "string",
}
```

In adressInfo, I concatenate the strings Address, City, Region, Postal Code and Country, the single strings, I need to declare them for reverseMap for the post method.

Someone who gives me a tip?

Sorry for my English, is not sufficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide properties from web api response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55805578/hide-properties-from-web-api-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EmployeeDto>>> GetEmployees()
        {

          return await _context.Employees
                     .Select(i=> new EmployeeDto
                     { 
                        employeeId=i.EmployeeId,
                        lastName=i.LastName,
                        firstName=i.FirstName,
                        adressInfo=i.Address
                      }
                    .ToListAsync();
        }}
```