# How to use ShouldSerialize[MemberName]() to Conditionally Serialize Element Within Property of Object Where Property is a List?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class "Hospitalization" which I need to Serialize as an XML string. That class has a property "ActiveDiagnoses" which is a list of type "DiagnosisCode".

In that collection, only the elements with the property Order with a value of less than three should be included in the serialized string.

Here is an example (which fails to only serialize the DiagnosisCodes with an order less than 3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlConditionalSerializationOnListExample
{
    [XmlRoot]
    public class Hospitalization
    {
        public string PatientName { get; set; }
        public DateTime AdmitDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DiagnosisCode")]
        public List<DiagnosisCode> ActiveDiagnoses { get; set; }
    }

    public class DiagnosisCode
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string CodeSet { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public int Order { get; set; }

    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hospitalization hospitalization = new Hospitalization() { PatientName = "Test Patient", AdmitDate = DateTime.Now.Date };

            List<DiagnosisCode> Dxs = new List<DiagnosisCode>()
            {
                new DiagnosisCode(){Code="Z99.81", CodeSet="ICD10", Order = 1}
                ,new DiagnosisCode(){Code="Z99.0", CodeSet="ICD10", Order = 2}
                ,new DiagnosisCode(){Code="Z98.5", CodeSet="ICD10", Order = 3}
            };

            hospitalization.ActiveDiagnoses = Dxs;

            string HospitalizationXml = String.Empty;
            XmlSerializer Ser = new XmlSerializer(hospitalization.GetType());
            //XmlSerializer Ser = new XmlSerializer(Hospitalization);

            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                Ser.Serialize(writer, hospitalization);
                HospitalizationXml = writer.ToString();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hospitalization object as represented by XML string:\n{0}", HospitalizationXml);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

}
```

My first thought was to set change the line where I assign the Dxs variable as the value for the ActiveDiagnoses property with a foreach loop which would conditionally add an XmlIgnore attribute to each DiagnosisCode with an order property value above 2 but apparently you [aren't able to do that dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397519/programmatically-add-an-attribute-to-a-method-or-parameter).

I then found a couple of examples of people using ShouldSerialize() Methods to determine whether or not a property would be serialized:

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698844/how-to-use-shouldserializemembername-method-for-a-property-of-type-object)
[Example 2](https://blog.jsinh.in/shouldserialize-conditional-xml-serialization-using-csharp/)

The difference between my scenario and the ones linked above is that Example 1 adds a ShouldSerialize() method for a property which isn't a List and although the second does add the ShouldSerialize() method for a List property, that method determines weather or not the entire list of elements is serialized, not particular elements within it.

I attempted to add the following method to the DiagnosisCode class:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeDiagnosisCode()
{
     return Order < 3 ? true : false;
}
```

However it had no effect. I tried to move that method to the Hospitalization class but got a compile error as would be expected because the compiler doesn't know what I'm referring to with the Order property.

I did end up with a workaround by doing the following:

1: Change the Hospitalization class to have two lists of DiagnosisCode objects, where one of them is marked as to be ignored when serializing as XML.

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Hospitalization
{
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdmitDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DiagnosisCode")]
    public List<DiagnosisCode> ActiveDiagnoses { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<DiagnosisCode> NonBillableDiagnoses { get; set; }
}
```

2: Change my Main() method to add each diagnosis in a loop and determine which of the two Lists to add the DiagnosisCode to based on its OrderIndex at that point in time.

```
//hospitalization.ActiveDiagnoses = Dxs;

hospitalization.ActiveDiagnoses = new List<DiagnosisCode>();
hospitalization.NonBillableDiagnoses = new List<DiagnosisCode>();

foreach (DiagnosisCode dx in Dxs)
{
    if (dx.Order < 3)
    {
        hospitalization.ActiveDiagnoses.Add(dx);
    }
    else
    {
        hospitalization.NonBillableDiagnoses.Add(dx);
    }
}
```

That solution works ok but I'd like to know if there's a way where I could use the ShouldSerialize method in the way I intended as described above.

Any help/ suggestions you can provide I'd greatly appreciate.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization Much more robust approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just not the intended purpose of the `ShouldSerialize` pattern. If you need to transform your data before serialization, just do it in code, as you're doing it already.

If you want to keep it in your `Hospitalization` class, you can filter the list there in the property's getter, like so:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Hospitalization
{
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdmitDate { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<DiagnosisCode> ActiveDiagnoses { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DiagnosisCode")]
    public List<DiagnosisCode> SerializableDiagnoses { get { return ActiveDiagnoses.Where(d => d.Order <= 2).ToList(); } }
}
```